# jsonapi-resources conditionally disable paginator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, jsonapi-resources

I use [jsonapi-resources gem](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) in my Rails app. One of my resources is using [pagination](http://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.8/guide/resources.html#Pagination). There are cases when I want to disable the pagination and make sure that user will get back **all the results**.

I tried custom implementation with some custom filter, but failed.

I tried passing "weird" values to paginator, but that did not help (examples for paged paginator):

- `/api/v1/bars?page[size]=-1` - value not allowed
- `/api/v1/bars?page[size]=0` - value not allowed
- `/api/v1/bars?page[size]=999999` - sure, this might work, but it is 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got exactly the same problem today and found this unanswered question.

Below is how I dealt with the problem.

```
class CustomPaginator < PagedPaginator
  attr_reader :limit, :offset, :disable_pagination

  def initialize(params)
    @disable_pagination = params.nil?
    super
  end

  def apply(relation, _order_options)
    disable_pagination ? relation : super
  end
end
```

and in the resources I wanted to use the `CustomPaginator` I just added `paginator :custom` like below:

```
class UserResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  paginator :custom
  ....user implementation
end
```

now whenever i want to use the paginator i need to explicitly use paginations params when I do the request to the server and when I don't use them I will get full unpaginated response.

The class implementation is not perfect (duh!) but it's just to show you the general concept